# Könnte man das ganze "welch- + Substantiv" als ein Relativpronomen verwenden?

Tags: relative-pronoun

Im folgenden Zitat bin ich mit einer merkwürdigen Verwendung von "welch + Substantiv" konfrontiert:

> Und demgemäß sind auch die wahrgenommenen äußeren Dinge nicht
>   Komplexionen von Empfindungen; sie sind vielmehr Gegenstände von
>   Erscheinungen, **welche Gegenstände** als Komplexionen von
>   Eigenschaften erscheinen, deren Gattungen in einem eigenen Sinne
>   analog sind denen, die bei Empfindungen bestehen.

Im Grammatikbuch von Duden lautet eine Stelle:

> Als Begleiter eines Substantivs wird **welcher** usw. mitunter **bei
>   Abstrakta** gebraucht, mit denen der Inhalt oder ein Teilinhalt des
>   übergeordneten Satzes wiederaufgenommen wird:
>
> Sie möchte ihr Haar färben lassen, mit **welcher Absicht** ich gar
>   nicht einverstanden bin.
>   Es sagte "Guten Abend", **welchen Gruß** sie mit einem Nicken erwiderte.

Aber "welche Gegenstände" im obigen Zitat stimmt nicht völlig überein mit dem Schema "welch- + Abstrakta", denn natürlich dürften "Gegenstände" hier nicht als Abstrakta für ihren übergeordneten Satz verstanden werden.

Wofür benutzt man "welch- + Substantiv"? Könnte man allgemein das ganze "welch- + Substantiv" als ein Relativpronomen verwenden?

Comment: Meiner Meinung passt das Beispiel nicht zur zitierten Dudenstelle. Das fett gedruckte *welche* ist ein normales Relativpronomen; um sicherzustellen, dass es sich nicht auf *Erscheinungen* sondern auf *Gegenstände* bezieht, wird das Substantiv wiederholt.

Answer (score 2):

Dies ist weniger eine Frage der Grammatik, vielmehr eine solche des Stils und des Ausdruckes. Welcher Stil im oben angeführten Beispiele ein recht altertümlicher ist. Der geneigte Leser wird wohl zustimmen, dass ein Werk, welches heute verfasst, füglich andere Mittel wählte, den leuchtenden Sinn aus der Worte waberndem Nebel emporzuführen.